# Appcelerator Titanium fireEvent in webview to use native iOS/Android functionality

Tags: appcelerator

I am new to Titanium and trying to find a solution or a good explanation on how to use Titanium API when in a webview. I have included all my code for the necessary parts of this demo.

What I'm trying to do is fire the native camera functionality from win4.html (see below). The documentation is not that great in the api.

I have a pretty basic setup in my **app.js**:

```
var tabGroup = Titanium.UI.createTabGroup();

var win1 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    title: "HTML",
    backgroundColor: "#000",
    url:"windows/win4.js"
});
var tab1 = Titanium.UI.createTab({
    title: "HTML",
    icon: "KS_nav_ui.png",
    window: win1
}); 


var win2 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    title: "Tab 3",
    backgroundColor: "#000",
    url:"windows/win3.js"
});
var tab2 = Titanium.UI.createTab({
    title: "Camera",
    icon: "KS_nav_ui.png",
    window: win2
});
```

**win4.js** (HTML - createWebView setup):

```
var win = Titanium.UI.currentWindow;
var webview = Titanium.UI.createWebView({url:'win4.html'});
win.add(webview);
Ti.App.addEventListener('showCamera', function() {
          tabGroup.activeTab = tab2;
});
```

**win4.html** (Pure HTML called by **win4.js**):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
        <style type="text/css">

            body {
                background: #87e0fd;
                background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #87e0fd 0%, #53cbf1 40%, #05abe0 100%);
                background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#87e0fd), color-stop(40%,#53cbf1), color-stop(100%,#05abe0));
                background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #87e0fd 0%,#53cbf1 40%,#05abe0 100%);
                background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #87e0fd 0%,#53cbf1 40%,#05abe0 100%);
                background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #87e0fd 0%,#53cbf1 40%,#05abe0 100%);
                background: linear-gradient(top,  #87e0fd 0%,#53cbf1 40%,#05abe0 100%);
                filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#87e0fd', endColorstr='#05abe0',GradientType=0 );
            }
            p {
                text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
            }
            .container {
                margin: 0 auto;
                overflow: hidden;
                width: 90%;
            }
            .left {
                float: left;
            }
            .right {
                float: right;
            }

        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function Init() {
                var left = document.getElementById("left");
                left.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                    Ti.App.fireEvent('showCamera');
                });
            }       
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="Init()"> 

        <div class"container">

            <div id="left" class="left">    
                <p>
                    left content here                       
                </p>                        
            </div>          
            <div class="right">     
                <p>
                    right content here                      
                </p>        
            </div>

        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

**win3.js** (Native Camera Call):

```
Titanium.Media.showCamera({

    success:function(event)
    {
        var cropRect = event.cropRect;
        var image = event.media;

        Titanium.Media.saveToPhotoGallery(image);

        Titanium.UI.createAlertDialog({title:'Photo Gallery',message:'Check your photo gallery'}).show();       
    },
    cancel:function()
    {

    },
    error:function(error)
    {
        // create alert
        var a = Titanium.UI.createAlertDialog({title:'Camera'});

        // set message
        if (error.code == Titanium.Media.NO_CAMERA)
        {
            a.setMessage('Device does not have video recording capabilities');
        }
        else
        {
            a.setMessage('Unexpected error: ' + error.code);
        }

        // show alert
        a.show();
    },
    allowEditing:true
});
```

How can I make a click event on the #left trigger the native camera within my app?

Answer (score 0):

You've defined your windows with a url to your JavaScript file, which creates a new JavaScript context for each window. Therefore, tab2 is not defined in win4's context, so when you try to switch the tab, it won't work.

Rather than placing your app listener in win4, put it in app.js. Ti.App events are global, and app.js is the only JavaScript context that knows about all the variables you want to access.